# inconsistency in NSManagedObjectContext.fetch(_:) method documentation

Tags: ios, core-data

In the documentation for [NSManagedObjectContext.fetch(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506672-fetch), in the method definition, there is only one parameter `request`, but in the description section, it says there are two parameters `request` and `error`. Why the difference?

[image]

Comment: The `error` will be *thrown*. The description is taken from the Objective-C API where there is a second parameter.

Comment: ah ok. Its just a bit strange that `error` is classified as a `parameter`. They should have a section just for `error` that are thrown, like what java did with `exception`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a result of how Objective-C and Swift interoperate.  A common pattern in Objective-C is for a function to modify an `Error` reference if there was a problem, and if you look at the Objective-C declaration of that function you see:

```
 - (NSArray *)executeFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request 
                       error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error;
```

With the introduction of try/throw/catch in Swift, the pattern that has been adopted is for functions declared in that way to `throw` the `Error` rather than use a side-effect and modify a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

What meant by error is that before fetch line you specify a try catch block , that will catch the error (thrown) it's not a parameter so you have to wrap it insdie the do-catch , if you tried to remove try it will give a compile error

```
do {

    let result:[People] = try managedContext.fetch(request)

 }
 catch let error as NSError
 {
   print(error)
 }
```

Comment: so the `error` parameter does not indicate we need to pass in an instance of `Error, but it is telling us we need to enclose any call to `NSManagedObjectContext.fetch(_:) in a `try-catch` block?

Comment: yes , to report the failure of executing a specific fetch